# Multiprocessing, selenium. Не могу закрыть ненужные браузеры после завершения цикла

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, multiprocessing

Не могу закрыть ненужные браузеры после завершения цикла!
`os.system("taskkill /pid chromedriver.exe /f")` - решает проблему, но, когда цикл идет по второму кругу, он выдает ошибки типа [WinError 10054], [WinError 10061] и просто останавливает процесс.
Как видите, тестил много чего, но того, чего хотел не нашел. Надо, чтобы после окончания цикла заметались все следы и запускались новые процессы.

```
def main():
  while True:
    get_item()
    get_url_json()
    get_url_post()
    p = Pool(processes=4)
    p.map(multi_work,users_urls)
    time.sleep(2)
    p.terminate()
    p.close()
    p.join()
    # os.system("taskkill /im chromedriver.exe /f")
    # os.system("taskkill /im chrome.exe /f")
    # os.system("taskkill /pid chromedriver.exe /f")
    # os.system("taskkill /pid chrome.exe /f")



if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Если есть вариант как лучше поступить, подскажите, возможно я пытаюсь сделать то, что не возможно

```
def multi_work(url):
    driver_head.get(url=url) 
    id = re.search('/(\d+)-', driver_head.current_url).group(1)
    driver_head.get(f"https://example.com/api/v2/users/{id}?localize=false")
```

Comment: А нельзя ли перевести на русский заголовок вопроса?

Comment: В конце функции нет очищения драйвера. Если поставить `driver.close()`,код просто упадет и на повторе цикла 
@Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA

Comment: И зачем вы делаете `p.terminate()`, нельзя как-то нормально дождаться завершения работы? Вроде в селениуме можно как-то подождать, пока страница загрузится.

Comment: Я тестил все что мог найти. Надо, чтобы открылся драйвер, запустились 4 процесса, чтобы они прошли по списку из 40 ссылок(4х10) и после того как они выполнили этот процесс, все следы стерлись, для нового цикла всего кода. Там 2 функции основные, первая собирает список, вторая работает с этим списком.@CrazyElf

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите закрывать браузер после каждой итерации, то это автоматически означает, что в начале итерации вам нужно его открывать, т.е. заново драйвер создавать. Вы, судя по всему, это делаете один раз, до цикла. Потому код и падает, если добавить закрытие.

Правильно будет открыват браузер в начале `multi_work` и закрывать в конце:

```
from selenium import webdriver

def multi_work(url):
  with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
      driver.get(url=url) 
      id = re.search('/(\d+)-', driver.current_url).group(1)
      ...
```

На месте `webdriver.Chrome` можете сделать нужную вам инициализацию, как/если вы сейчас это делаете до цикла.

Answer (score 0):

Первая функция. Создал отдельный драйвер в функции

```
def get_item():
    hhd = webdriver.Chrome(
        executable_path=r"C:\Users\...\chromedriver.exe",
        seleniumwire_options=proxy_options,
        chrome_options=chrome_options)
    with hhd as d_head:
```

Вторая Функция. Создал отдельный драйвер в функции

```
def multi_work(url):
    ddh = webdriver.Chrome(
        executable_path=r"C:\Users\...\chromedriver.exe",
        seleniumwire_options=proxy_options,
        chrome_options=chrome_options)
    with ddh as driver_h:
```

Мейн. Просто подставил киллер процессов(taskkill)  между первой и последующими функциями. Таким образом где-то между процессами завершаются процессы chrome и chromedriver, при этом цикл всей функции `def main():` не обрывается.

```
def main():        
      while True:
        get_item()
        time.sleep(1)
        os.system("taskkill /im chromedriver.exe /f")
        time.sleep(1)
        os.system('taskkill /im chrome.exe /f')
        time.sleep(1)
        get_url_json()
        get_url_post()
        p = Pool(processes=4)
        p.map(multi_work, users_urls)

        time.sleep(100)
```